# How to convert a quicktime 3d model .mov format into multiple images

Tags: file-formats, 3d, quicktime

I've tried exporting 3d model lab into images sequence format after going through this below answer.
[exporting .mov vr to multiple still frames](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4033/exporting-mov-vr-to-multiple-still-frames),

but all I can see same image output with different names?

Is there any other procedure to convert the 3d model mov file to panorama jpeg image?